# Calculating the rotation point between 2 sets of points

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations

I've been trying to solve this for a while but I can't figure it out.
I have 2 sets of points: **p1**, **p2** and **p1'**, **p2'**.

*p1(x1,y1), p2(x2,y2) and p1'(x1',y1'), p2'(x2',y2')* all known values.

Those 2 sets are the same but are rotated around a point (**$p_c$**). I want to find that point's (**$p_c$**) coordinates.

[small sketch of both data sets with the center of rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Hg2.png)

At first I tried this (I set some points and rotated them around the coordinates (0.5,-0.5) so that I know if I find the correct result):

Since I know all the points, I took this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1'\\ 
y_1'\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
cosθ & -sinθ & x_c\\ 
sinθ & cosθ & y_c\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
y_1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let's note it this way: $B = XA$

I isolated X to get this: $X=BA^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ and naively thought I'd get my $x_c$ and $y_c$, but the resulted X was
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.7071 & -0.7071 & -0.2071\\ 
0.7071 & 0.7071 & -0.5\\
3.7919e^{-16} & 3.8203e^{-15} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This transformation matrix is correct, when I tranform my points using it, the point's shift to where they should be. But although there's -0.5 for $y_c$, the $x_c$ is wrong.

Next I thought I'd try and take this "formula?/operation": *(It takes a x,y point, translates to the origin of the axis, rotate, and translate back, basically rotating around a point that is not the origin)*
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1'\\ 
y_1'\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & x_c\\ 
0 & 1 & y_c\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
cosθ & -sinθ & 0\\ 
sinθ & cosθ & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -x_c\\ 
0 & 1 & -y_c\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
y_1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let's not it this way: $C1 = T*R*T^{-1}*C0$ where is known everything but **x** and **y** (**θ** the angle of the line is easely calculated)
But I don't know how to isolate $T$ and $T^{-1}$ (which if I could I'd just have $T*T^{-1}$ which wouldn't get me very far.)

Do you have any insight on what I should be doing? I feel like I'm way off course on this one.

Comment: You cannot invert $A A^T$ , it is a rank 1 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that the perpendicular bisectors of segments $p_1 p'_1 $  and $p_2 p'_2$ pass through the center of rotation $p_0$.  Therefore, if

$n_1 = p'_1 - p_1 $

$n_2 = p'_2 - p_2 $

and

$m_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} (p'_1 + p_1 ) $

$m_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} (p'_2 + p_2 ) $

and

$p_0 = (x, y) $

then

$n_1^T (p_0 - m_1) = 0 $

$n_2^T (p_0 - m_2 ) = 0 $

So that by matrix inversion, we get the center of rotation $p_0$

$p_0 = \begin{bmatrix} n_1^T \\ n_2^T \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} n_1^T m_1 \\n_2^T m_2 \end{bmatrix} $

To get the angle of rotation, find the angle between the vector $p'_1 - p_0$ and $p_1 - p_0$.  This angle is equal to the angle between the vectors $p'_2 - p_0$ and $p_2 - p_0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for both your solutions. I tried to develop this solution using some test points and got my center of rotation. Would you mind explaining this part: $n_1^T (p_0 - m_1) = 0$ ? I don't understand how you get from the previous operations to this one

Comment: The perpendicular bisector of line segment $p_1 p'_1$  passes through the midpoint $m_1$ and is perpendicular to the line segment itself, which is given by the vector $n_1 = p'_1 - p_1 $, therefore, if $q$ is any point on this bisector, then the vector $(q - m_1)$ is perpendicular to $n_1$ , which means their dot product is zero.  Hence, $n_1 \cdot (q - m_1 ) = 0 $ is the equation of this line.   Finally $ a \cdot b = a^T b $.

Comment: i see, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, where the rotation matrix $R$ is calculated first, and then the center of rotation.

We have the following relation between $p_1, p'_1, p_2 , p'_2$ and the center of rotation $p_0$

$p'_1 = p_0 + R (p_1 - p_0) $

$p'_2 = p_0 + R(p_2 - p_0) $

Subtracting

$p'_2 - p'_1 = R (p_2 - p_1)$

Let $b = p'_2 - p'_1 $ and $ a = (p_2 - p_1) $

$a$ and $b$ are known vectors, having the same length $r$, thus

$ a = r ( \cos \theta_1 , \sin \theta_1 ) $

and

$b = r (\cos \theta_2, \sin \theta_2 ) $

Since

$R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi && - \sin \phi \\ \sin \phi && \cos \phi \end{bmatrix} $

then

$R a = r ( \cos(\phi + \theta_1 ) , \sin(\phi + \theta_1 ) )$

Comparing this with $b$, we deduce that the rotation angle $\phi$ is given by

$ \phi = \theta_2 - \theta_1 $

So matrix $R$ is now known.  Back to the original equations

$p'_1 = p_0 + R (p_1 - p_0) = R p_1 + (I - R) p_0 $

From this equation we get

$p_0 = (I - R)^{-1} ( p'_1 - R p_1 ) $

Note that the determinant of $(I - R)$ is

$| I - R | = (1 - \cos \phi)^2 + \sin^2 \phi = 2 - 2 \cos \phi $

So the determinant is $0$ (singular matrix) only in the case $\phi = 0 $, which corresponds to no rotation at all.

Comment: I don't see the point of this solution compared to you other one (that I have upvoted).

Comment: You're probably right, it is an inferior solution compared to the other one.